# Can I use the crosstab fxn when my table has this unique format?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgres-crosstab

Here's a sample of my table/results. I'm tracking whether these events were a direct or indirect result of a promotion sent.

```
select * from test.generate_mkt_report(3379,'2001-01-01', current_date) limit 1;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGSlw.png

And I'm looking to create a crosstab report like this - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkzth.png).

The only values possible in the columns referenced in the screen shot are `direct`, `indirect`, and `null`.

Not sure if it's possible to use the crosstab fxn.